# Attachment file location

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Hi guys just wondering dynamics crm 2011 stores its attachment files? Eg when I attach a pdf to an entity, where would this pdf is stored? Is it stored in a file system or database?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stored to the database in the annotation entity. [Here's the SDK article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334398.aspx) for some more info.